# DateTime value NULL when UI culture is Auto

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I'm having a application which I want make compatible for both US and UK region, and for US region I'm able work with date successfully, where as for UK below is the scenario

I have date field, when date is less than or equal to 12 it works fine but when date is greater than 12 it gives null value to PUT method.

Also I'm using below code to send data,

```
$http.put(apipath + '/REST/Method/' + date);
```

And I'm having below web config

```
<globalization culture="Auto" uiCulture="Auto" enableClientBasedCulture="true" />
```

Also have checked in Network tab of chrome, and the date field data is being sent in UK format correctly! But the PUT method receives NULL when date is greater than 12.

Comment: The single most difficult thing in a software is to handle is dates. When you say the dates are going to the app in UK format, is your API is designed to accept the dates in that format?. When dealing with dates, it is always good to use certain standard date format, I prefer to use the dates that are passed to an app in this format 'yyyy-mm-dd'

Comment: @Thangadurai "The single most difficult thing in a software is to handle is dates." - it could be worse; it could be *times* (shudder)

Comment: @Thangadurai And here I thought the single most difficult thing to handle was users.

Comment: What is the value of `date` when it fails? Are the slashes escaped properly so that it doesn't think there's more than one parameter?

Comment: @fredrik date value is null when it hits the controller, yes slashes are escaped properly as I'm getting dates when month is less than 12

Comment: Month can never be greater than 12... Auto culture will most likely take the culture of the server, not the user that makes the request. Define a date format everyone who uses the API must use (such as the [ISO format 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parsing the date to 'yyyy-mm-dd' in client side javascript, before posting the data worked.

Used moment.js for the same.